# I am getting EF's "Unable to load the specified metadata resource" error, but only in VS2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

I have a web application which uses MVC4, EF6.1 connecting to SQL Server 10

1) Starting in VS2012 on dev web server, all fine.

2) Starting in VS2015 on dev web server, get error.

3) Retry in VS2012 on dev web server, get error.

Difference between 2) and 3) is that the ".vs" folder gets added after loading the solution file in VS2015.

4) Delete ".vs" folder, Retry in VS2012, all fine.

So it seems there is something in ".vs" that is upsetting my EF from running, and causing the error.

Other Information:

Web config, which looks ok to me:

```
<add name="EntityConnectionString"
connectionString="metadata=res://Entity.Models/Model.csdl|res://Entity.Models
/Model.ssdl|res://Entity.Models/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=myserver;Initial 
Catalog=DevDatabase;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=True&
quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Provider Manifest Token, tried both 2008 and 2012 in EDMX:

```
ProviderManifestToken="2008"
```

It seems that there is something in ".vs" that is preventing the web application from starting in VS2015. Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is your issue, but I experienced similar flakiness moving from VS 2013 to VS 2015 where the web server would just hang on an EF call. This is what I ended up doing:

> 1) Move the [.suo file](http://visualstudioadventures.com/2015/11/21/where-is-the-suo-file-in-visual-studio-2015/) from VS 2013 that lives next to the
>   solution file out to a temp folder (just in case).
>
> 2) If you have opened the solution in VS 2015 previously, move the .vs
>   folder to temp as well.
>
> 3) Start VS 2015 with no .suo files.
>
> 4) Set your solution properties, but don't run solution. Startup project, etc.
>
> 5) Exit VS 2015 and there should be a fresh .suo file in the .vs/sln/v14 folder.
>
> 6) Go back into VS 2015 and everything works.

Also check that your Nuget packages are OK.

Comment: Thanks for this. .suo advice did not work. Checking .nuget packages, but surely if it works in VS2012 then it should work in VS2015 ie my nuget packages must be fine,

Comment: Have you tried something like this: http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/08/13/38628/

Answer (score 0):

I did solve it in the end. What I did not share, as I did not think it was relevant, was that I am using Devart's Entity Developer. I was using version 5.7 so upgraded to 5.8.8. Also I regenerated the model from the VS2015 Model project back to that same project using the new Entity developer. It now works.

My feeling is that the EDMX and related files got confused when I copied them from another folder rather than regenerating them within the destination folder.

Thanks for all assistance.